# DNS ERROR using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dns

Hello I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 and I love the interface. However I am disappointed that I cannot access the web. I my wired and wireless connections are present but when I try to connect to the Internet using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox I receive a dns server error? I am a novice to intermediate geek type so this is kinda foreign to me. Please make it simple or basic for me to understand how to fix his problem.  It may even be something I have overlooked. Any help you can provide would be lovely.

Ciao,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Does the name resolution work from the terminal at all?

1. Open the terminal and type `host google.com` which should print its IP address.
2. If that works it's likely to be a browser configuration/proxy/etc. related problem.
3. If that doesn't work, run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and make sure there's at least one line that starts with nameserver and is followed by an IP address.
4. If there's no line like this, either your resolvconf is misconfigured, or your DHCP server doesn't offer the DNS resolvers.
5. If there is a `nameserver x.x.x.x` try querying that resolver with `host google.com x.x.x.x` and if it fails try the Google DNS: `host google.com 8.8.8.8`.

I assume you have your interface configured, so that you have a default route and you can communicate with it.

Comment: I was able to get the goodle ip address, but still am having issue's connecting to the internet with either Google Chrome, or Firefox. I am still receiving the dns error. Not sure how to proceed at this point. I can still connect to my router wired, or wirelessly.

Comment: @Thomas: Please provide *detailed* information. Exactly what commands have you tried and what is the exact output of each one? Post the output. What is the exact text of the "dns error" and when do you see this message?